# angular2-query-builder drop down value is not getting reset/updated

Tags: angular

I am having an issue regarding changing the dropdown value when its respective field is changed, it is still showing the same data or let's say data that is initialized first. This issue occurring only when I use custom components or simply any changes like "select" tag for mimicking dropdown.

These are the query and config that I have provided

```
  query = {
    condition: "and",
    rules: [
      { field: "age", operator: "Equal to", value: "young" },
      { field: "gender", operator: "<=", value: "m" },
      {
        condition: "or",
        rules: [
          { "field": "age", "operator": "<", "value": "old" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

  //-------------------------------
  config: QueryBuilderConfig = {
    fields: {
      age: {
        name: 'Age',
        value: "age",
        type: 'category',
        operators: ["=", "<=", ">"],
        options: [
          { name: 'Young', value: 'young' },
          { name: 'Old', value: 'old' }
        ]
      },
      gender: {
        name: 'Gender',
        value: "gender",
        type: 'category',
        operators: ["=", "<=", ">"],
        options: [
          { name: 'Male', value: 'm' },
          { name: 'Female', value: 'f' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<section class="custom-query-builder">

  <query-builder [(ngModel)]='query' [config]='config' #addNewRule>

    <ng-container
      *queryButtonGroup="let ruleset; let addRule=addRule; let addRuleSet=addRuleSet; let removeRuleSet=removeRuleSet">

      <div class="add-ruleset btn__action--class" (click)="addRuleSet()">
        <app-svg [name]="'add-circular'"></app-svg>
        <div>Group</div>
      </div>

      <div class="add-rule btn__action--class" (click)="addRule(); consoleElement(addNewRule)">
        <app-svg [name]="'add-circular-empty'"></app-svg>
        <div>Rule</div>
      </div>

      <!--<button type="button" (click)="removeRuleSet()">- Ruleset</button> -->
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *queryRemoveButton="let rule; let removeRule=removeRule;">

      <div class="remove-rule btn__action--class" (click)="removeRule(rule)">
        <app-svg [name]="'minus'"></app-svg>
        <div>Remove</div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>

    <!--col name-->
    <ng-container *queryField="let rule; let fields=fields; let onChange=onChange">
      <div class="query__filed">
        <div class="query__label">Column Name</div>
          <select [(ngModel)]="rule.field">
            <option *ngFor="let opt of fields">{{opt}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </ng-container>

    <!--col filter-->
    <ng-container *queryOperator="let rule; let operators=operators; let onChange=onChange">
      <div class="query__filed">
        <div class="query__label">Filter</div>
        <select [(ngModel)]="rule.operator">
          <option *ngFor="let opt of operators">{{opt}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </ng-container>

    <!--col label-->
    <ng-container *queryInput="let rule; let field=fields; let options=options; type: 'category'">
      <div class="query__filed">
        <div class="query__label" (click)="options">Value</div>
      <select [(ngModel)]="rule.value">
        <option *ngFor="let opt of options">{{opt}}</option>
      </select>
      </div>

    </ng-container>

  </query-builder>
</section>



<div class="output">{{query | json}}</div>
<!-- <div class="generate__code" (click)="generateWhereCode()">generateCode</div> -->
<!-- <div class="generated__code" *ngFor="let ele of codeDataTemp;let i = index">
  <div>{{i+1}}. {{ele}}</div>
</div> -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add values for the options of `*queryField` select:

```html
<option *ngFor="let opt of fields" [value]="opt.value">{{opt.name}}</option>
```